# Oracle - ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis in query generated by Odata query generator

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

this is the query generated by an Odata Sql query generator and I am on Oracle 12c

```
SELECT ID 
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE (
        NAME LIKE 'abc' = true
      )
;
```

and the error it generates is

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 14
```

Any ideas on how to fix the query ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063684/is-it-possible-to-expose-data-from-oracle-using-odata) might be of some use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about "Odata Sql query generator", but - if you want to fix this query, then it would be

```
select id from my_table where name like 'abc'
```

On the other hand, that's same as

```
select id from my_table where name = 'abc'
```

so perhaps you actually meant to use wildcards:

```
select id from my_table where name like '%abc%'
```